# Texmaker language babel

Tags: 14.04, latex

I installed `texmaker` on ubuntu 14.04 using the Ubuntu Software Center.

After entering command: `\usepackage[croatian]{babel}`
I get following error:

```
! Package babel Error: Unknown option `croatian'. Either you misspelled it
```

I used `texmaker` on Ubuntu 12.04 and this command worked fine. Now characters like `đ` can't be spelled.
Is there a way to enable croatian language package?
Thanks

Comment: Note that `babel` and `inputenc` are two different thinks. The first one is for typographic localized conventions and spelling.  The second is for inputing non-ASCII character (like yours). So, do you want to use `babel` or input non-ASCII characters?

Comment: What do you suggest to do to have non-ASCII characters? This are all user packages I'm using 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{abstract}
\usepackage[croatian]{babel}
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{braket} 
\usepackage{wrapfig} 
\usepackage{graphicx}

Comment: Just remove babel, it should work.

Comment: I removed just {babel} part and error was found. I remove whole usepackage and again i wasn't able to see that character in pdf.

Comment: Try if [this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7448792/) compiles. If so, add the package `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to the preample.

Comment: Now i get this error: ! Font T1/cmr/m/n/10=ecrm1000 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found

Comment: So the file I gave you is not compiling with that error?

Comment: I copied commands form link you gave me and paste it in texmaker and got that error after pressing "PDFLaTeX"

Comment: That's strange. Can you post the content of the .log file (on paste.ubuntu.com and then here the link)?

Comment: Sure, here is log file after error i got while running commands you gave me: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7448872/

Comment: Is the .tex file saved with utf8 encoding and TexMaker set for utf8 encoding? TexMaker>Options>Configure>Editor>Font encoding

Comment: yes, it is utf8

Comment: Also the file itself?

Comment: I don't know how to check it.

Comment: `file PATH_TO_FILE/NAME_OF_FILE.tex` where you put the right path and name.

Comment: "LaTeX 2e document, UTF-8 Unicode text"

Comment: I noticed now this: `Missing character: There is no � in font nullfont!` In what I posted above, when you copy it, can you see the `đ`?

Comment: Here is a screenshot of what i entered: http://i60.tinypic.com/i3w2lv.png

Comment: I'm sorry, the previous comment was dumb. Rendered fonts always confuse me ;) But it is really strange that it does not find your character. Can you please compile via terminal and post the output?  `pdflatex FILE_PATH/FILE_NAME.tex`

Comment: Here it is: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7448971/

Comment: Install `texlive-latex-recommended` and try again after that.

Comment: Have you installed `texlive-lang-european` ? The old `texlive-lang-croatian` have been superseded, I think by this one.

Comment: I found solution, sorry for wasting your time, it was dumb of me for not checking it sooner, I'll post it soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Ubuntu Software Centre, after typing "texmaker" and going on "more info", there are optional add-ons, and I was missing the one named: "Tex Live: metapackage depending on all TeX Live language packages (texlive-lang-all)".

After installing it there was no error and non-ASCII characters are visible now in pdf file.